# How to connect Android Studio With Php Server?

Tags: php, android, laravel, android-studio, xampp

I am trying to connect my android project with laravel api , I tried to change the url from localhost to ip of my computer and make my computer and my phone on the same network , my phone can access xampp from browser but it gives me 404 not found every time i make a request while i could make that request through typing `http://localhost:8000/` but when i change it to `http://192.168.1.8:8000/` it returns The requested URL was not found on this server

Comment: `my phone can access xampp from browser ` If it can then how do you do that? And if you can then why later tell us about a 404? Dont understand.

Comment: i mean that i make my phone and my laptop on the same netwrok and i wrote the IPv4 Address in the browser of my phone and it opened the xampp file .. when i try to make request from retrofit with the ip address rather than localhost in url it gives me 404 not found

Comment: You should use the same url with browser and retrofit. And there can never be localhost in it. Never means: also not when you use a browser on your Android device. Confusing info you give.